# Does anyone know of a source of goat parmesan in the New York Area or a farm in New York that produces it?

Tags: cheese, goat

I read in a previous Q that someone had subbed goat parmesan for regular. I am looking for a farm source in New York State or nearby.

Comment: You might try looking for 'Caprino Romano' which is a hard grating cheese made w/ goat's milk.  More common is Pecorino Romano, which is made from sheep's mik.  (note that 'romano' in the US is often cow's milk, unfortunately)

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not from New York (Charlotte) I know that Trader Joe's sells many different goat cheeses including cheddar and parmesan. A quick Google showed at least 3 Trader Joe's in NYC.